# Click Link doesn't work while Copy-Paste link it works properly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

This is the weirdest issue I ever found on HTML and, to be honest, I don't have a clue where to start from. Any idea will be very helpful as I am stacked and I don't know what else to look for.

### Description of the Application

In my company, we build a project, that consists of the application management dashboard and the customers' front end part.

When a user is registered in our application, we sent an email that comes with a button for Auto Login into his account.

In the application management then, we have per user account a button that generates the exact same link as the button, to allow the application administrators to access the user account in the front end, by copy and paste the generated link.

### The problem

Either we copy and paste the auto-login URL from the administration dashboard or from the link in the body of the users' email, we could auto-login with no problems.

If we click the link in the email body, the auto-login URL doesn't work. *(By doesn't work, we mean that the user is logged in, but some pages acting as the user is not logged, while some other acting as the user is logged in. At the same time, if we perform a browser refresh, the user is again normally logged in.)*

At the same link, in the email body, if we perform a Right Click -> Open link in a new tab, the link it works normally. The user is getting auto-logged in and all the operations are working as they should.

### Logs

Our system, for both cases *(either click, right-click or copy-paste)*, doesn't log any errors in any logging sides *(console and browser console)*

### What we have tried so far

We have copied the links in a plane empty `index.html` file, that comes only with two links like that:

```
Double Quoted Attributes:
<br>
<a href="https://u3067134.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=......" target="_blank">
    Link Button As It Appears In the Email Body
</a>
<a href="http://our-app.tld?Authorization=......" target="_blank">
    The resolved Application URL After the SendGrid redirection
</a>
<br>
Single Quoted Attributes:
<br>
<a href='https://u3067134.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=......' target="_blank">
    Link Button As It Appears In the Email Body
</a>
<a href='https://our-app.tld?Authorization=......' target="_blank">
    The resolved Application URL After the SendGrid redirection
</a>
<br>
Double Quoted Attributes with Encoded URL Parameters:
<br>
<a href="https://u3067134.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=URL_ENCODED_PARAMETERS_HERE" target="_blank">
    Link Button As It Appears In the Email Body
</a>
<a href="https://our-app.tld?Authorization=URL_ENCODED_PARAMETERS_HERE" target="_blank">
    The resolved Application URL After the SendGrid redirection
</a>
<br>
Single Quoted Attributes with Encoded URL Parameters:
<br>
<a href='https://u3067134.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=URL_ENCODED_PARAMETERS_HERE' target="_blank">
    Link Button As It Appears In the Email Body
</a>
<a href='https://our-app.tld?Authorization=URL_ENCODED_PARAMETERS_HERE' target="_blank">
    The resolved Application URL After the SendGrid redirection
</a>
```

But again, the links don't work with a click. At the same time, both other methods work with the exact same links *(right-click -> open in a new tab, or copy-paste the link in a new browser tab)*

Any idea of what could be wrong with this situation, please?

Comment: When you hover over the links you see the exact same thing as if you right click -> copy link address (that should be working)?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy yes. All the information I see everywhere is the exact same, but the only problem I have is when I click the link :( T_T

Comment: Only thing I can right away is that some links are http and some https. Is that intended? Other than that you might try and isolate your login process to see if it behaves the same

Comment: You get my +1, but unless you can try to reproduce in a snippet somewhere I'm not sure I'll be able to guess where the issue is coming from...

Comment: @Rie both links working, either http or https, but to make it more clear, I am going to remove the https from the examples :)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy me neither. I have no idea where this problem comes from :( Just looking for any hint to start looking for solutions T_T

Comment: hint: Create a new project and slowly copy over your code to the fresh project and see when/if it breaks. There has to be something in your code that makes it not work as expected. From the snippet you posted here it looks fine. Has to be something else. If possible you can also do that in a codesandbox and link that sandbox here so we can have a look

Comment: Maybe something with headers? Referer/origin etc are probably different.

Comment: @Cray you maybe right !! :) Thank you. I am going to check and then I will coma back with updates

Comment: @Cray any docu on that..? I would like to understand, as it doesn't really ring a bell for me,

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have to do with headers as proposed by Cray. The headers are identical :( If any other hint in your heads guys will be very nice to listen. Again thank you very much for your efforts and your help :)